# open protected excel file with com, but the running excel does not support addins

Tags: excel, vbscript, com, excel-addins

I need to open the encrypted excel file from code, and the end user can also edit or save the opened file. Then I found a way to handle it by using com:

https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/previous-versions/office/troubleshoot/office-developer/automate-excel-from-c

However, The opened excel application does not support excel addins.

for example: the excel setting like

[excel setting 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3QfZp.png)
[excel setting 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JMgp4.png)

when open excel.exe normally，it's like:

[normally open, correct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tUCKP.png)

but when use com to open excel.exe by the code, it's like:

[open from code, incorrect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQkX1.png)

the addins disappear.

Also, if you reconfig addins option, addins appear again. So I think there may have no initialization when excel.exe was started.

**Is there any way to start open encrypted excel file by excel.exe from code, and all excel function are fine?**

Here is the code with vbs(the link below is c code):

```
Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set oWorkbook = oExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\melon\Desktop\excel\excel tests\chat&sample exam.xlsm", 0, 0, 5, "76350e01-a0bd-44c6-9e4d-0df382c2d789")
oExcel.Visible = true
```

Answer (score 0):

Programs started with COM are started by COM with the slash `/a` parameter. This means Automation is starting the program so it should load clean.

> /a
>
> Starts Word and prevents add-ins and global templates (including the
> Normal template) from being loaded automatically. The /a switch also
> locks the setting files.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/command-line-switches-for-microsoft-office-products-079164cd-4ef5-4178-b235-441737deb3a6

Comment: By the link, I did not found the solution to solve this problem. I found a way to solve this problem. I use COM API to query excel addins config, and just reset it. so that the problem solved. But I don't think it's the best way to solve it.